# understanding a crash log - KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, crash

I am trying to solve a crash which happens every now and then unpredictably and at different points of time during the use of my application.
I would very much appreciate any help as I am lost regarding what it can be, I did converted to ARC and used @AutoReleasePool where needed, still I am getting this from time to time...

Date/Time:       2011-11-09 11:30:40.661 +0100
    OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0 (9A334)
    Report Version:  104

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x2fd74da8
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x36e1e786 -[NSArray isEqualToArray:] + 14
1   CoreFoundation                  0x36e271cc -[NSArray isEqual:] + 64
2   CoreFoundation                  0x36e1ef7e -[NSDictionary isEqualToDictionary:] + 310
3   CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d9c -[NSDictionary isEqual:] + 64
4   CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d40 -[__NSCFDictionary isEqual:] + 48
5   CoreFoundation                  0x36e1ef7e -[NSDictionary isEqualToDictionary:] + 310
6   CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d9c -[NSDictionary isEqual:] + 64
7   CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d40 -[__NSCFDictionary isEqual:] + 48
8   CoreFoundation                  0x36e1e876 -[NSArray isEqualToArray:] + 254
9   CoreFoundation                  0x36e271cc -[NSArray isEqual:] + 64
10  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1ef7e -[NSDictionary isEqualToDictionary:] + 310
11  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d9c -[NSDictionary isEqual:] + 64
12  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d40 -[__NSCFDictionary isEqual:] + 48
13  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1ef7e -[NSDictionary isEqualToDictionary:] + 310
14  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d9c -[NSDictionary isEqual:] + 64
15  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d40 -[__NSCFDictionary isEqual:] + 48
16  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1e876 -[NSArray isEqualToArray:] + 254
17  CoreFoundation                  0x36e271cc -[NSArray isEqual:] + 64
18  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1ef7e -[NSDictionary isEqualToDictionary:] + 310
19  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d9c -[NSDictionary isEqual:] + 64
20  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d40 -[__NSCFDictionary isEqual:] + 48
21  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1ef7e -[NSDictionary isEqualToDictionary:] + 310
22  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d9c -[NSDictionary isEqual:] + 64
23  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d40 -[__NSCFDictionary isEqual:] + 48
24  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1e876 -[NSArray isEqualToArray:] + 254
25  CoreFoundation                  0x36e271cc -[NSArray isEqual:] + 64
26  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1ef7e -[NSDictionary isEqualToDictionary:] + 310
27  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d9c -[NSDictionary isEqual:] + 64
28  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d40 -[__NSCFDictionary isEqual:] + 48
29  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1ef7e -[NSDictionary isEqualToDictionary:] + 310
30  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d9c -[NSDictionary isEqual:] + 64
31  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d40 -[__NSCFDictionary isEqual:] + 48
32  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1e876 -[NSArray isEqualToArray:] + 254
33  CoreFoundation                  0x36e271cc -[NSArray isEqual:] + 64
34  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1ef7e -[NSDictionary isEqualToDictionary:] + 310
35  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d9c -[NSDictionary isEqual:] + 64
36  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d40 -[__NSCFDictionary isEqual:] + 48
37  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1ef7e -[NSDictionary isEqualToDictionary:] + 310
38  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d9c -[NSDictionary isEqual:] + 64
39  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d40 -[__NSCFDictionary isEqual:] + 48
40  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1e876 -[NSArray isEqualToArray:] + 254
41  CoreFoundation                  0x36e271cc -[NSArray isEqual:] + 64
42  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1ef7e -[NSDictionary isEqualToDictionary:] + 310
43  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d9c -[NSDictionary isEqual:] + 64
44  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d40 -[__NSCFDictionary isEqual:] + 48
45  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1ef7e -[NSDictionary isEqualToDictionary:] + 310
46  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d9c -[NSDictionary isEqual:] + 64
47  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d40 -[__NSCFDictionary isEqual:] + 48
48  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1e876 -[NSArray isEqualToArray:] + 254
49  CoreFoundation                  0x36e271cc -[NSArray isEqual:] + 64
50  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1ef7e -[NSDictionary isEqualToDictionary:] + 310
51  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d9c -[NSDictionary isEqual:] + 64
52  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d40 -[__NSCFDictionary isEqual:] + 48
53  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1ef7e -[NSDictionary isEqualToDictionary:] + 310
54  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d9c -[NSDictionary isEqual:] + 64
55  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d40 -[__NSCFDictionary isEqual:] + 48
56  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1e876 -[NSArray isEqualToArray:] + 254
57  CoreFoundation                  0x36e271cc -[NSArray isEqual:] + 64
58  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1ef7e -[NSDictionary isEqualToDictionary:] + 310
59  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d9c -[NSDictionary isEqual:] + 64
60  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d40 -[__NSCFDictionary isEqual:] + 48
61  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1ef7e -[NSDictionary isEqualToDictionary:] + 310
62  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d9c -[NSDictionary isEqual:] + 64
63  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d40 -[__NSCFDictionary isEqual:] + 48
64  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1e876 -[NSArray isEqualToArray:] + 254
65  CoreFoundation                  0x36e271cc -[NSArray isEqual:] + 64
66  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1ef7e -[NSDictionary isEqualToDictionary:] + 310
67  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d9c -[NSDictionary isEqual:] + 64
68  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d40 -[__NSCFDictionary isEqual:] + 48
69  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1ef7e -[NSDictionary isEqualToDictionary:] + 310
70  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d9c -[NSDictionary isEqual:] + 64
71  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d40 -[__NSCFDictionary isEqual:] + 48
72  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1e876 -[NSArray isEqualToArray:] + 254
73  CoreFoundation                  0x36e271cc -[NSArray isEqual:] + 64
74  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1ef7e -[NSDictionary isEqualToDictionary:] + 310
75  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d9c -[NSDictionary isEqual:] + 64
76  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d40 -[__NSCFDictionary isEqual:] + 48
77  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1ef7e -[NSDictionary isEqualToDictionary:] + 310
78  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d9c -[NSDictionary isEqual:] + 64
79  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d40 -[__NSCFDictionary isEqual:] + 48
80  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1e876 -[NSArray isEqualToArray:] + 254
81  CoreFoundation                  0x36e271cc -[NSArray isEqual:] + 64
82  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1ef7e -[NSDictionary isEqualToDictionary:] + 310
83  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d9c -[NSDictionary isEqual:] + 64
84  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d40 -[__NSCFDictionary isEqual:] + 48
85  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1ef7e -[NSDictionary isEqualToDictionary:] + 310
86  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d9c -[NSDictionary isEqual:] + 64
87  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d40 -[__NSCFDictionary isEqual:] + 48
88  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1e876 -[NSArray isEqualToArray:] + 254
89  CoreFoundation                  0x36e271cc -[NSArray isEqual:] + 64
90  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1ef7e -[NSDictionary isEqualToDictionary:] + 310
91  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d9c -[NSDictionary isEqual:] + 64
92  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d40 -[__NSCFDictionary isEqual:] + 48
93  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1ef7e -[NSDictionary isEqualToDictionary:] + 310
94  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d9c -[NSDictionary isEqual:] + 64
95  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d40 -[__NSCFDictionary isEqual:] + 48
96  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1e876 -[NSArray isEqualToArray:] + 254
97  CoreFoundation                  0x36e271cc -[NSArray isEqual:] + 64
98  CoreFoundation                  0x36e1ef7e -[NSDictionary isEqualToDictionary:] + 310
99  CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d9c -[NSDictionary isEqual:] + 64
100 CoreFoundation                  0x36e27d40 -[__NSCFDictionary isEqual:] + 48
```

this thread carry on going with the same syntax around 300 lines...

Comment: looks like a stack overflow - got any recursion in your app - any arrays or dictionaries nested inside themselves etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With no code to look at the best guess is a method is recursively calling itself, either directly or indirectly and not reaching termination.  Possibly there is an entry in the `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` that references back into itself.

Try pausing the execution in Xcode if possible to get an idea where in your code this is happening.

Post some code.

Comment: I would gladly, yet my application is rather large - code wise, can u direct me to what part of the code can be relevant ?

Comment: Try pausing in Xcode to get an idea of the code.  Put NSLogs and/or breakpoints in your code to localize the problem area.  Look for areas where `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` are going enumerated or processed.

Comment: +1 for "Possibly there is an entry in the NSDictionary or NSArray that references back into itself".  I'm sure that is what is happening here.